# How to understand powers of operators in the Petz-Renyi relative entropy?

Tags: entropy, quantum-information

The Petz-Renyi relative entropy is defined for positive semi-definite operators $\rho$ and $\sigma$ on a finite-dimensional Hilbert space as
\begin{equation}
D_\alpha(\rho||\sigma) = \frac{1}{\alpha - 1}\log \frac{\hbox{Tr}[\rho^{\alpha} \sigma^{1-\alpha}]}{\hbox{Tr}[\rho]}
\end{equation}
where $\alpha \in (0,1)\cup (1,\infty)$. (I found this as  [Eq. (3) while reading this paper](https://aps.arxiv.org/pdf/1306.3142.pdf).)

Since $\rho$ and $\sigma$ are positive semi-definite they can be diagonalized. Let $\sigma = UDU^\dagger$ with $U$ unitary and $D$ diagonal. Should I understand that $\sigma^{1-\alpha} = U D^{1-\alpha} U^\dagger$ in the relative entropy equation?

(Motivation for the question: My initial concern upon reading the equation above was how it applied to pure states. If $\alpha = 2$, $\sigma^{1-\alpha} = \sigma ^{-1}$. But $\sigma$ may not be full rank and may not have an inverse.)

Comment: Yes, this is generally how any (analytic) function can be interpreted when applied to matrices. (See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analytic_function_of_a_matrix#Diagonalizable_matrices).)

Comment: If $\sigma$ is not invertible, you can take the limit $\lim_{\alpha\to 2}D_{\alpha}(\rho\Vert\sigma)$, which is finite if $\operatorname{im}(\rho)\subset\operatorname{im}(\sigma)$.

Comment: Got it. Thank you for the helpful comments!